# 'TelegramClient' object has no attribute 'get_input_peer'

Tags: python, telethon

When running a script with telethon library, it gives an error:
'TelegramClient' object has no attribute 'get_input_peer'
The latest version of telethon installed

Code:

```
import asyncio
from telethon import TelegramClient, functions

api_id = ''
api_hash = ''
phone_number = ''

client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash,
                        device_model="iPhone",
                        system_version="14.8.1",
                        app_version="8.4",
                        lang_code="en",
                        system_lang_code="en-US")


async def main():
    await client.start()

    confirmation_code = input('Введите код подтверждения: ')
    await client.sign_in(phone_number, confirmation_code)

    await client.get_dialogs()

    while True:
        try:
            await client(functions.messages.SaveDraftRequest(
                await client.get_input_peer('me'),
                'бе',
                reply_to_msg_id=None
            ))
            await asyncio.sleep(15)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Ошибка: {e}')
            await client.start()
            continue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Tried reinstalling the telethon library, but nothing worked

Comment: What are you truing to do?

Comment: I'm trying to make a script via the api of telegram that will write a specific message to my favourites so that my account is always online

Comment: With 'favourites' do you mean the 'saved messages' ?

Comment: yesssssssssssss

Answer (score 1):

TelegramClient doesn't have get_input_peer. telethon.utils has this method, and TelegramClient has get_input_entity, if that's what you were looking for.